# Solving a simple functional equation

Tags: equation-solving

As a newbie to Mathematica, I am currently trying to test what are the software capabilities and limitations. Thus, I have reached the following problem.

What I want to do, is to construct a functional equation of three functions (2 known and 1 unknown) and solve it analytically. For example, consider the following code:

```
f[x_] := x^2
g[x_] := x^5
RSolve[h[x] == g[x] * f[x], h[x], x]
```

where the solution for `h[x]` is trivially `h[x] = x^7`. However, Mathematica throws the following error:

[image: error message]

So, is something like that possible?

Comment: Omit `,x`  in the end of your code and  try `Solve` instead of `RSolve`.

Comment: The solution is x^7 not x^5 what is trivial by inspection. MMA version 12.1 returns: {{h[x] -> x^7}} what is correct

Answer (score 2):

The use of `RSolve` is for recurrence equations. Try running the following

```
f[x_] := x^2
g[x_] := x^5
Solve[h[x] == g[x]*f[x], h[x]]
```

Note also that the obvious solution you mentioned should be $x^7$; I am assuming you have a typo in what you wrote.

Comment: yes sorry, of course it was a typo.

I tried Solve  and it did give back a result.

thank you!